# Es posible guardar datos en una base mysql mediante un metodo?

Tags: java, mysql, método

Hola comunidad disculpen soy un aprendiz en la programación java y me gustaría conocer si es posible realizar un registro a bd **MySql** mediante un método `public string`, agregando las propiedad de los datos a almacenar en una bd MySql, perdón por la pregunta apenas llevo un mes estudiando java

Answer (score 2):

Para poder hacer conexiones con BBDD en Java, haz uso del driver JDBC.

1-Estableces la conexion
2-Con el objeto resultante de esa conexion realizas cualquier operacion.

Aqui tienes un tuto:

http://uh-tis.blogspot.com.es/2014/04/curso-de-java-como-conectar-java-con-una-base-de-datos-forma-basica.html

Espero que esto te sirva:

```
public void insertoConsulta(Connection con,String consulta){
     Statement st=con.createStatement();
     st.execute(consulta);
    //st.executeUpdate(consulta)   esto si es un insert por ejemplo
}
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio mucho!

Comment: De nada Sommer! si te ha resuelto la duda marcala con el tick verde la respuesta.